# Apache Tika 1.22 fails to extract body text from eml file

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, apache-tika, eml

In earlier versions of Tika eg. 1.14, The parser could retrieve content body from an eml file. The new version 1.21 > does not get the content body of an eml file.

To test this download the tika 1.22 jar and run it. Drag and drop an eml file into the dialogue box and you will notice, the parsed file does not display the content. All metadata files are retrieved.

Comment: Did you try turning on recursion into embedded resources?

Comment: @Gagravarr thanks..that worked